# Can a person studying Vedas or reciting Vedas keep a beard?

Tags: vedas, practice

Is it compulsory for a person studying the Vedas to remove all facial hair and just have a Shikha/shendi?

Comment: @user1981528 you might be correct, but there also might be a vedic approach towards doing rituals

Answer (score 2):

It is recommended **not to have facial hairs** at least while one is reciting the Vedas. We have the following reference from the Dharma Sutras of Baudhayana 4.5.1-3:

> Now I will proclaim the rites of the Rg-, Yajur-, and Atharva-vedas
>   by which a man will quickly obtain his heart’s desires.
>
> 2 He should perform the rites only after purifying his body by the
>   soft recitation of prayers, burnt offerings, oblations, and
>   restraints. He will not attain success otherwise.
>
> **When he is about to engage in the soft recitation of prayers,
>   make burnt offerings and oblations, and practise restraints, a Brahmin
>   should first get his head and beard shaved** and his nails clipped on
>   an auspicious day and under an auspicious lunar mansion during the
>   fortnight

Comment: I think the bold text is only for someone who starts studying the vedas for the first time. In personal experience I have seen that people who start studying the vedas begin to get a stubble since they can shave on only particular days and not daily like the others. And I believe a shika is needed on the head and it shouldn't be completely shaven (not sure if this is sect specific).

Comment: Shikha should not be shaved generally speaking. That is mentioned in the same scriptures. Because otherwise the person will be considered as "naked from the top" @user1952500